# Finding highest and lowest value of rainfall in Raptor

Tags: javascript, arrays, module, raptor

Updated version.

I had figured out my previous issue with it but am still unsure how to do the last part. I do not know how to get the number that goes inside of the bracket instead of getting the value that is stored inside of it. The array consists of 12 numbers and for example I am looking for the highest value which might be 20 and was entered in the 4th spot. I can only figure out how to get it to display the 20 but I want to display the 4 instead. It has user input so the number that should be displayed may vary and I am unsure how to accomplish this.
I only need the arrays number to be displayed for the highest and lowest values. I don't know if I am using the wrong kind of array for this not.

[image: The main is the first section which is calling the other functions]

[image: The getInput function and assigns the entered values to one of 12 numbers in the array]

[image: The calculateTotal function which just adds all the values up.]

[image: The calculateAverage function which takes all the numbers entered and finds the average]

[image: The findHigh function which figures out which number entered is the highest. I have another function almost identical to this but finding the lowest. These are the two that need to show the arrays number and not the value that is saved inside of it.]

[image: displayResults function page which will display the values.]

Comment: I'm confused on which section you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry it looked different when I was posting it. The third picture is the one where it keeps stopping me at and saying that highestValue isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a couple issues but easy fixes. This only goes to fix image 3 which is highestValue.

1.) When you are setting `highestValue` you are saying highest value is equal to [January, amountOfRain]. You need to have it say `highestValue <- data[1,2]`. This will point it to `amountOfRain`.

2.) You need to change the name of either your `Call` or your variable `highestValue` because it's conflicting.

Give those a try and let me know what you get.